# What causes color change with two adjacent mesh cubes with same material

Tags: uv

I am creating a model of a floating dock and have two adjacent mesh cubes both with the same image texture material and uv wrapped the same way yet the color looks different on each. One appears a gray color and the other more brownish. What causes that and how do I rectify?

[image]

Comment: It could be the light source/HDRI

Comment: Thanks Emir, the same thought just came to me after viewing the model from different angles.

Comment: Strange though that both meshes are on the same plane (and joined together) so I would have thought the light falling on one would fall from the same angle on the other one.

Comment: @JohnArnold could be the differing interpolation of normals. Is there any topology in the meshes we can't see? Could you show us the wireframe / share a sample on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: if you provide a blend file - you would attract more people (e.g. me)

Comment: Sorry Chris.    I tried to upload the blender file after doing a pack resources but the resulting blender file was over 340Mb yet without doing the pack resources it is less than 2Mb and the only texture image (material) is quite small so I don't understand that. Anyway I uploaded the blender file to the 'cloud' (Mega) and the download link is here  https://mega.nz/file/Krh3kJ4J#eBd9l4qDwSk4pQNlnj8CdGdtk5rap7uCGaajWdwoz5A